# RemoteDataError Using pandas datareader

Tags: python, finance, pandas-datareader

Hi I rescued an old program I did time ago, and I am having some issues.

I am just testing this:

IN:

```
pdr.data.DataReader('DOW',start='2020-1-1', end='2020-12-31', data_source = "yahoo")
```

OUT:

```
RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DOW/history?period1=1577847600&period2=1609469999&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history
```

in fact if I put that Url in my Chrome it works fine and web returns me all data. But that line is not working in python. Any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Seem they have some issue with API and trying to solve it. That happened in past and engineers in Yahoo have solved the issue. I have seen a comment somewhere on the internet today where they accept issues on their side and promise to solve it soon. I do experience the same problem

> You can check the last comment here  [link for comment check](https://365datascience.com/question/remotedataerror-unable-to-read-url-for-yahoo-using-pandas-datareader/)